# RabbitMQ language independent library

Tags: rabbitmq, flume

We are planning on integrating RabbitMQ to push all the application related events. 
Problem is that our applications are written in different languages (Perl, Python, Java...), if we start using Rabbit everywhere, it would mean using the different RabbitMQ libraries and as is often the case, we will also write an abstraction layer in all the languages, so it would mean that I'll need to maintain different code bases to write to Rabbit.
Isn't there any language independent way to get around this problem? I'm looking for a tool, which could potential listen to messages from different applications(say over socket interface) and then push everything to Rabbit. Basically I'm looking for something along of lines of a tool like FLUME, where we can connect multiple input pipes and then FLUME writes to Hadoop.
Any suggestions how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your problem.

Btw, even if I don't like as solution: 
you could use the [`RabbitMQ C`](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c) library, build your layer over there and then link the library to your language as JNI for java etc

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I might be missing something, but how can I use the abstraction library with different languages, we have like 5-6 programming languages, it will not work in my opinion;
Another option is that all my application could write to disk and then a common application could read from the disk and write to Rabbit, but here disk usage can be a problem, i'm looking for a more light weight solution to this problem.

Comment: `C` is cross-platform  and you can bind it with different languages. 
Write on the disk? what? you will have the same exactly problem. 
But maybe it is my fault, I did not get your aim. you want an single implementation for different languages. With `C`  you can do that. ( even if I don't like )

Comment: I see that I could write it in C, but if i'm not wrong, I still need to write different bindings like JNI for Java, Cython for Python and something similar for Perl, I assume that there will be maintenance work with these extensions too, as and when I change my C library, i might have to change these wrappers too.
The aim is reduce code duplication, I don't want to maintain 6 different libraries for writing to Rabbit